# PHP foreach loop with form data

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, foreach

I am trying to get data from html form via php and put it through loop x times for each input.

This is the code:

```
    foreach ($_GET['first_input_field'] as $val)
{
$temp_second_field = $_GET['second_input_field'][$value];
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $temp_second_field ; $i++)
{

echo $val;

   }
$i=0;
}
```

the form:

```
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[1]" id="field_1" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[1]" min="1" max="4">
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[2]" id="field_2" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[2]" min="1" max="4">
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[x]" id="field_x" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[x]" min="1" max="4">
```

Form has a + button that adds both fields (auto increases first_input_field and second_input_field number).

I am trying to repeat first_input_field value x times where x is second_input_field value
and then echo it.

But i am getting Undefined index: error here. 
`$temp_second_field = $_GET['second_input_field'][$value];`

Ty for the help in advance.

Comment: If I understand you right, I think you just need to switch $val to $value or vice versa

Comment: What is the method of your `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put numbers in the HTML element name:

```
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[]" id="field_1" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[]" min="1" max="4">
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[]" id="field_2" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[]" min="1" max="4">
<input type="text" name="first_input_field[]" id="field_x" value="Text 1"><input type="number" name="second_input_field[]" min="1" max="4">
```

Edit: Further to that, you're looping through things using `$value` which isn't set in your code, and actually that `for` loop isn't necessary:

```
foreach ($_GET['first_input_field'] as $k=>$val) {
    $count = $_GET['second_input_field'][$k];
    str_repeat($val, $count);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited to remove the need for the inner loop.

Comment: while you are here, i have a second problem now :)
echo $val . '0,30';
this 0,30 should go up each time echo resolves by some exact number (like +30) so 30,60

Comment: Explode, increment, and implode. Please open a new question if you need more explanation than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$temp_second_field = $_GET['second_input_field'][$value];
```

to

```
$temp_second_field = $_GET['second_input_field'][$val];
```